# TransformListener has unconnected trees

Tags: rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have multiple tf frames which some of are dynamically published by the robot_state_publisher and some are static transformations.

When using the tf.TransformListener i get the error message that there are two or more unconnected trees.
Running rosrun tf view_frames also shows the unconnected trees.

However, rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree shows the correct tf tree, rviz can show the correct tf tree and even rosrun tf tf_echo source_frame destination_frame returns the transformation values.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT1:

rosrun tf tf_monitor source_frame target_frame returns the correct chain, however every frame is published by "unknown publisher" and the only broadcaster node is called "unknown". Could this be the reason why view_frames or the TransformListener are failing?

EDIT2:

TF2 can do the transformation with the following piece of code:

```
tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
tf2_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tf_buffer)
tf_buffer.lookup_transform('world', 'halcon_camera', rospy.Time())
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268302/transformlistener-has-unconnected-trees/) by [bennypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8396/bennypi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-08**:
I can't be sure, but this sounds like something that could happen with a mixed TF1 / TF2 setup (static transforms, etc). perhaps @tfoote can help here?

**Comment by [bennypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8396/bennypi/) on 2017-08-08**:
You could be right because tf2 can do the transformation. I've added this to the question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-08**:
I don't want to suggest using some workaround when it's not necessary, but can you see whether setting `use_tf_static` (private param of `robot_state_publisher`) to `False` makes things work again? see [wiki/robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The python implementation of tf was unable to receive static transforms. This has been resolved in 1.11.9 which is in testing and will become available in the next sync.

[Changelog](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/indigo-devel/tf/CHANGELOG.rst) Specifically [#149](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/149) [#134](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/134)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0